# How to change Apigee's trace console HTTP method to POST

Tags: http-post, apigee, api-gateway

How to change *ApiGee* trace console HTTP method from GET to POST? There is only GET available by default and I cannot change it.

I have not enough rep to embed screenshot so here it is https://i.stack.imgur.com/bffQt.png

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is by using the API console.  Under the Send button on the Trace tool, click the link "Send with the API Console".  This will launch the console in a separate tab.  The API Console allows you to choose the request verb (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) as well as header parameters you might want to set.  You can start a trace session, send any request using the console, and then go back and see the results of sending the request.